# WiFi adapter TL-WN727N is not working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I am using Zorin OS 11. My wifi adapter( TP-link: model:TL-WN727N) is not working at all.

I typed "lsusb" in terminal, then the adapter showing as "Ralink MT7601U". So, that means the adapter is okay and the driver is not installed.

I searched in google and collect some drivers and commands but that's not working. There is some github link of the driver in askubuntu.com but the links are not valid now. They are like from 2014/2012.

Can you help me find the appropriate drivers for it?

Comment: Showing "Ralink MT7601U" does not mean that the driver is installed.
This means that the device is detected by the operating system.
Tell me what's going on after typing `uname -a`?

Answer (score 0):

You should try and compile the driver yourself. Here is direct download link from TP-Link website:
http://www.tp-link.com/res/down/soft/TL-WN727N_V4_150909.zip
They says it's for: Linux (Kernel version 2.6~3.16) and for TL-WN727N V4.
Hope that helps.